# i3 and xrandr put cursor on wrong position between monitors

Tags: ubuntu, i3, multi-monitor, xrandr

I'm using the latest Ubuntu version with the i3-gaps windows manager and I'm using xrandr for managing monitor positions. I am trying to switch the position of the monitors virtually, because by default i3 thinks the left monitor is on the right side and vice versa. I'm trying to use xrandr to switch them, and it works, except the cursor becomes broken. The cursor shows up on the right monitor, but it's registering clicks like it's on the left side. What command or tool should I use to fix this?

Comment: why don't you swap the monitors physically?

Comment: they are different monitors; one is my main 27-inch 144hz, the other is an older 24-inch 60hz. I'd like to keep my main in the nicer spot it is in than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using compton/picom by any chance? I had the exact same issue, and killing the compton process solved it for me. After setting the layout using xrandr, I can start compton again and everything is in the right place.

I am using the following compton version: `0.1~beta2+20150922` and xrandr v1.5.0.